# Easiest way to return 401 for angularJS URL

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-401

I've removed some pages from my site and would like to remove them from search engines, and I've concluded I need to do this using 401s - what's the best way to do this when using angularJS?

Comment: Your server should send 404 Page not found. I don't know why you concluded your server should send 401 Forbidden. Another option is have your server do 301 Permanent Redirect to a valid page.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the HTTP-status-code of an HTTP response from angular code, because angular is only a frontend framework.

What you instead want to do is set up your **webserver** to serve a 401 HTTP-status-code, e.g. Apache HTTP server.